# sliding solution jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I click on first time flip, it shows panel, then I click on panel, it will shows the sub-panel.

But when I click multiple times on flip, and then click single time on panel, then it works wrongly as the sub-panel shows and hides multiple times for single click.

What's the problem?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $('#panel').slideToggle("slow",function(){
        $('#panel').click(function(){
        $('#subpanel').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
  });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip,#subpanel
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel,#subpanel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>

<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="subpanel" style="display:none;">hello </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zgbfjnbs/  just separate click functions...

Comment: You mentioned what is the problem, but what is the desired behaviour..? should sub panel close as well while clicking flip..? or just the panel..? start with the desired behaviour, then your attempt and the issue you are facing with it. The desired behaviour is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Try Moving the .click on #panel out of the click handler for #flip.  Everytime you click flip you're readding the click handler for panel.